# Unwanted line break font change

Tags: css, text

I want multiple text styles in one line, but when I change the styles, the line breaks automatically.I made another page that does not have this problem, but I cannot find the difference. The header styles are below:

```
h1 {
font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
font-size: 0.9em;
font-weight: 400;
color: rgb(4,4,4);
text-decoration: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
line-height:normal;
font-style: normal;
letter-spacing: 0.15em;
}
h2 {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.9em;
font-weight: 700;
color: rgb(4,4,4);
text-decoration: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
line-height:normal;
font-style: bold;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
h3 {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 0.8em;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 1.6em;
color: rgb(4,4,4);
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
h4 {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 0.8em;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 1.6em;
color: rgb(4,4,4);
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
h5 {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 0.8em;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.6em;
color: rgb(4,4,4);
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: h1, h2 etc are block elements, so do not share a line with each other by default. You could set `display: inline;` or you could just use a different element type to mark the different styles.

Comment: Wrap in `span`, not 'h' tags.

Answer (score 0):

H1, H2, H3, etc are block elements. So instead of writing something like:

```
<h1>This is one font</h1><h2> and this is another.</h2>
```

Write it like this:

```
<span class="font1">This is one font</span><span class="font2"> and this is another</span>
```

Then give the classes of span1 and span2 different font-families.